# Using check state change to calculate for tables and show results

Tags: vb.net

i what to multiply a value of a text box with a decimal number when the check state of the check box changes from unchecked to checked but when ever i try it does not work .. this is what i have done so far but it is not working

```VB
Private Sub FuelOnlyCheckBox_CheckStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FuelOnlyCheckBox.CheckStateChanged

    Try
        If FuelOnlyCheckBox.CheckState = True Then

            Dim TotalCashEmolumentsint As Integer
            Dim FOLmtint As Integer
            Dim VHFint As Integer
            Dim TotalVHFint As Integer

            TotalCashEmolumentsint = Val(TotalCashEmoluments.Text)
            TotalVHFint = Val(TotalVHF.Text)
            VHFint = Val(VHF.Text)
            FOLmtint = Val(VFDLmt.Text)

            ' Calculating FO

            VHFint = TotalCashEmolumentsint * 0.05

            'Checking and deducting with limits
            If VHFint = FOLmtint Then
                TotalVHF = FOLmt
            End If

            If VHFint > FOLmtint Then
                TotalVHF = FOLmt
            End If

            If VHFint < FOLmtint Then
                TotalVHFint = VHFint + 0
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: And *what* does not work? Compile error, exception at runtime, wrong result?

Comment: @NicoSchertler results remains . whiles its not suppose to be that is y i say it is not working

Comment: So where in your code do you access the check box?

Comment: If you want to multiply by 0.05, I suggest define variables as Dobule, not as Integer. And replace "," with "." in textboxes.

Comment: In conditions TotalVHF or TotalVHFint ? Maybe TotalVHF.text ?

Comment: @capricorn i used double n still it did not work... i guess the problem is from  Private Sub FuelOnlyCheckBox_CheckStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FuelOnlyCheckBox.CheckStateChanged

Comment: `'Checking and deducting with limits` - what is TotalVHF? Can't see definition. If you want to set text in textbox, add `.Text` after textbox name... Check whether the names are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your values aren't changing when you check/uncheck the box is that **you've only written code for when the box is checked**. To tell your program what do when the box is unchecked, **you need to add an `Else` statement**.

For example:

```
If FuelOnlyCheckBox.Checked Then
    'Your code as written
Else
    'Alternate calculations
End If
```

Based on what I *think* you're trying to do, this might be more helpful:

```
Try
    Dim TotalCashEmolumentsint As Integer
    Dim FOLmtint As Integer
    Dim VHFint As Integer
    Dim TotalVHFint As Integer

    TotalCashEmolumentsint = Val(TotalCashEmoluments.Text)
    TotalVHFint = Val(TotalVHF.Text)
    FOLmtint = Val(VFDLmt.Text)

    If FuelOnlyCheckBox.Checked Then
        VHFint = TotalCashEmolumentsint * 0.05
    Else
        VHFint = Val(VHF.Text)
    End If

    If VHFint >= FOLmtint Then
        TotalVHF = FOLmt  'Undeclared variable. Should it be FOLmtint?
    Else
        TotalVHFint = VHFint
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

**EDIT:**

After taking another look, there is an even bigger problem than that: you've confused the `CheckState` and `Checked` properties. `CheckState` is an *integer* and `Checked` is a *Boolean*. So

```
If FuelOnlyCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
```

or

```
If FuelOnlyCheckBox.Checked Then
```

will give you the results you want, but

```
If FuelOnlyCheckBox.CheckState = True Then
```

**will do the opposite of what you want.** This is because `True` considered as an integer evaluates to 0, which is also the value of `CheckState.Unchecked`.

Comment: the answer still remains zero 0

Comment: @MastaPee, I accidentally used the `CheckState` property instead of `Checked`. (I guess I typed this up in VS and didn't pay attention to IntelliSense.) Hopefully the edit I just made fixes the problem. If not, you're going to have to be a lot more specific about your problem (i.e. which variable is the "answer," some test values and their expected results) for anyone to help you.